# Async functions - require .then to execute them?

Tags: async-await, ecmascript-2017

promises are executed only if you call .then on them
or this is how I learned it.

Async functions are what I understand functions "turned" promises. Do I need to call .then on them each time I want to invoke an async function?

```
async function loadStory(){}
....
loadStory()
or
loadStory().then
```

Comment: Apparently you learned it wrong. Promises are not "executed" at all. Where did you learn this?

Comment: ES8 `async functions` are nothing but syntactic sugar for a normal function that returns a promise.

Comment: async/await is part of ES2017, not ES7.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions are executed as per regular functions by invoking them as usual.

In order to make your code appear synchronous and utilise the benefits of async / await you'll need to prefix the call with `await`.

For example:

```
async function example () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve('hello');
    });
}

const myReturnedValue = await example();
```

Because of the `await` keyword, `myReturnedValue` will be the result of the resolved promise returned by the `example` function.